# How to specify a module (-m) when using the Python debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a Python module which I have to execute like this:

```
python -m ModuleA.ModuleB <someargs>
```

How can I configure the `-m` switch on VS Ccode's `launch.json`? The `args` section is for the script being executed, not for the python binary itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python launch configuration accepts a `"module"` instead of a `"program"`. It is used in [debugging specific Python applications](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types) such as Flask, Django, and Scrapy. Here is the [sample for a Flask app](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_flask-debugging) which seems similar to what you want:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "flask",            # <---------------------
    "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
    },
    "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--no-reload"
    ],
    ...
}
```

> As you can see, this configuration specifies `"env": {"FLASK_APP": "app.py"}` and `"args": ["run", "--no-debugger","--no-reload"]`. The `"module": "flask"` property is used instead of `program`.

So, given this sample workspace with folder `Q` containing `ModuleA.ModuleB`:

```
$ tree .
.
├── Q
│   └── ModuleA
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── ModuleB.py
└── .vscode
    └── launch.json
```

where ModuleB is:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(*sys.argv)
```

You can specify this *launch.json* configuration as:

```
{
    "name": "run-specific-module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Q",
    "module": "ModuleA.ModuleB",
    "args": [
        "123",
        "abc",
    ]
},
```

Running that gives this output in the terminal:

```
$  cd /path/to/Q ; env /path/to/python /path/to/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.91350/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 37343 -- -m ModuleA.ModuleB 123 abc 
('/path/to/Q/ModuleA/ModuleB.py', '123', 'abc')
```

which should be the same as:

```
$ python -m ModuleA.ModuleB 123 abc
('/path/to/Q/ModuleA/ModuleB.py', '123', 'abc')
```